# Проверить значения в массиве smatry

Tags: php, smarty

Есть массив, имеет значения:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(3) "371"
  [1]=&gt;
  string(3) "385"
  [2]=&gt;
  string(3) "369"
}
```

Значения могут быть на любых местах. Необходимо проверить есть ли в массиве значение 371, есть ли в массиве значение 385, есть ли в массиве значения 371 и 385 одновременно. Задача в том, что если есть хотя бы одно из этих значений, то записать в массив какое-то значение и больше не обращать внимание на эти числа.

Первые два условия, допустим, не сложные, но вот третье не могу понять как сделать. Я так понимаю, что сперва необходимо проверять существуют ли в массиве оба эти значения сразу и если нет, то проверять по отдельности.

```
{foreach $mass as $m}
   {if $m == "371"}
      {$cname[] = "1"}
   {elseif $m == "385"}
      {$cname[] = "1"}
   {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Пока нашёл только такое решение, может кто-то знает более правильное

```
{foreach $mass as $m}
   {if $m == "371" || $m == "385"}
      {if $cname[0] != "1" && $cname[1] != "1"}
         {$cname[] = "1"}
      {/if}
   {/if}
   {if $m == "369"}
      {$cname[] = "2"}
   {/if}
{/foreach}
```

В моём случае это выход, так как значение у меня может быть в одной из двух ячеек. Но это не выход, если ячеек может быть неопределённое количество.

Answer (score 0):

я бы сказал что такая логика не совсем подходит для самого представления и подобные проверки надо проводить на этапе бизнес-логики, а не представления.

но тем не менее. Никто вам не мешает в smarty использовать функции поиска `in_array`

То есть можете сделать цепочку проверок

```
{if in_array(371,$mass) && in_array(385, $mass)}...
{elseif in_array(371,$mass)}....
{elseif in_array(385, $mass)}...
{/if}
```

*в целом обычный вызов `in_array()` можно переписать в виде модификатора. Значение к которому применяется модификатор передается в функцию первым, а далее все параметры. Так что посольку сигнатура `in_array` это `($needle, $haystack)` то выглядеть это будет как `371|in_array:$mass`*

Возможно, от массива значений лучше перейти к ключам. Проверка наличия ключа в массиве куда проще, чем поиск самого значения. Тем более, если от ключа зависит итоговое значение:

```
[371 => 1, 385 => 1, 369 => 2]
```

в общем говоря, ваш последний фрагмент кода, можно изменить  на примерное такое (я правда не особо понял откуда в задаче берется `$cname` и т.п. и про какие ячейки речь):

```
{if $mass[371] || $mass[385]}
    {if !in_array($cname, 1)}
        {$cname[] = 1}
    {/if} 
{/if} 
{if $mass[369]}
    {$cname[] = 2}
{/if}
```

В использовании циклов здесь необходимости нет.